# Would Aspose.Word handle Table of Contents (TOC)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, ms-word, aspose

We're using aspose.word to create a report from a word template direct to PDF format. Now we're stuck at handling the TOC for the document. We need the TOC to be dynamic and make correct changes according to where the section is on the document.

Would aspose handle putting the correct page number to the correct category? And can anyone give a short example? The example on the aspose site wasn't helpful in this case.

We're using visual studio to make this site and it says on the aspose documentation that the setting for a TOC is set first on a regular word document then copy the field codes. So I'm approaching it this way, setting the TOC on the template itself then copying the field code to the C# code. Or am I over thinking it and all I need to do is make sure that the TOC is correct on the template itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked with Aspose for a bit, and as I recall, they don't really do any repagination, which is what would be necessary to properly regenerate a TOC with proper page numbers.

You may need to put an call into them. As I recall, their support was pretty easy to get in touch with. I didn't end up using their product because of some of the limitations, but for general use, it seemed pretty decent.